# How to resolve incompatible type error in functional programming in Java 8

Tags: java-8, spring-webflux

I'm getting error as "**Incompatible types. Required ExchangeFilterFunction but Map was inferred to Mono:no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Mono conforms to ExchangeFilterFunction**".

Code:-

```
 public ExchangeFilterFunction getNewExchangeFilter(Tuple2 <String, WebClient> serviceConnectionDetails,
          MultiValueMap <String, String> queryParams) {

          logger.info("Calling auth server to get new access token..................");
          Mono<AccessToken> accessToken =  commerceAccessTokenService.getUserAccessToken(serviceConnectionDetails, queryParams);
          return accessToken.map(token -> oAuthToken(token.getAccessToken()));   

      }

      private ExchangeFilterFunction oAuthToken(String token) {
        return (clientRequest, exchangeFunction) ->
            exchangeFunction
                .exchange(ClientRequest
                    .from(clientRequest)
                    .header("Bearer " + token)
                    .build()
                );

      }
```

I'm calling auth server to get access token which is a Mono and in oAuthToken() I'm trying ty set it in header and returning ExchangeFilterFunction. Please advise how to resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: getNewExchangeFilter is supposd to return an ExchangeFilterFunction. accessToken is a Mono. Mono.map() (see https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) returns a Mono. So your method returns a Mono, not an ExchangeFilterFunction.

Comment: An apple is an apple is an apple. Telling the compiler "trust me, it's a banana" won't turn an apple into a banana. You need to understand what a Mono is, and probably to change your design in order to return a Mono<ExchangeFilterFunction>. reactive programming is really really hard. If you don't know what a type cast is yet, you should probably stay away from reactive programming.

Comment: I understand what type casting is however what I do not understand is how to read that access token from Mono which is returned and set it into ExchangeFilterFunction because I need both objects at some point as both have different purpose as per the design. If I block my async call using .block() to read access token from Mono then technically I'm breaking the reactive programming concept here. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way if I can read it from Mono without using .block and finally returning ExchangeFilterFunction to my WebClient.

Comment: EIther you block until the Mono is resolved (which defeats the purpose of reactive), or you accept the fact that your method is asynchronous and non-blocking, and thus can't return an ExchangeFilterFunction, but must return a Mono<ExchangeFilterFunction>.